# list box in gtk

Tags: c, linux, listbox, gtk

I have a file in which some text is stored. Now I want to display the text in a list box using `gtk`. How can I do this?

Also the values are changing dynamically. Is there a way to refresh the listbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done using model-view architecture in GTK. The view is a [`GtkTreeView`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTreeView.html), and you can associate it with a [`GtkListStore`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkListStore.html), which you can update dynamically. The tree view will refresh automatically when you update the list store.

You might also want to read this [overview of tree and list widgets in GTK](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/TreeWidget.html).